# Eclipse | code template for System.out.println()

Tags: java, eclipse

I have got the following as the code template for `System.out.println` in Eclipse

```
System.out.println(${word_selection}${});${cursor}
```

I was under the impression that I could write a text, select it, enter `ctrl+space`, and then write sop - and Eclipse will write the proper line for me. But this is not happening. Can anyone help me understand the way `${word_selection}` is supposed to work?

Comment: isn't there already a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the text and press `ctrl+space` *twice*. The first time you do it, "default proposals" are shown. The next time the applicable code templates are shown. Unfortunately you cannot type the name of the template since that will overwrite the selected text, but you can select it with arrow keys and press return.

It will look like this after the second `ctrl+space` on an Eclipse with default templates:

[image: sysout template]

Comment: Hitting ctrl+space twice did the trick. However, the text is wrapped as is and without the "...". Should the template not have been `System.out.println("${word_selection}${}");${cursor}`

Comment: @Techforgood The way the template is by default, `"` are not added. You could modify the template yourself to add them if that is waht you want, i.e. make it `System.out.println("${word_selection}"${});${cursor}`

Comment: @K Erlandsson, it seems like we are thinking the same thing. Nice.